# Sync Itunes with my pc

Tags: data-synchronization

I want to add new purchased songs to my itunes library. When I plug in my phone to my work pc and I am logged into my itunes, I get a box asking to remove songs movies books.  Do I approve or will all songs and ringtones be deleted from my iphone? Or once I approve and sync will I be able to put all the songs and ringtones back onto my iphone?

Comment: With which computer has your iPhone synced in the past?

Comment: Is the AppleID from the PC iTunes the same of your iPhone? Do you have the same appleID for iCloud and iTunes? The normal behavior of it is to **always merge things**. But you said it is asking for **removal**, so I cannot precisely answer you, and I believe @nohillside is on the right way.

Comment: @Prado Not sure about the merging part here, also not sure the AppleID plays a role for iTunes syncing. Let's see what the OP adds to the question.

Comment: I have mine on PC iTunes, 2 MacOS iTunes and new Music App, and iPhone, they are all synced using the same AppleID **but I sync all my music and tunes with iCloud**, so AppleID plays an important role at my case. I already had some doubts about missing thing, until I test very well then now I am sure about the always merge behaviour. But we need more input from the OP to know better his settings, as you mentioned.

Comment: ICloud syncing is completely different from iTunes syncing. ITunes syncing is possible with one computer only, syncing with another computer usually results in audio tracks synced from the from the first computer getting deleted.